# How analog & Digital Communication Can be through same 2 wires?

Tags: communication

How analog & Digital Communication Can be through same 2 wires?
Which protocal is used in 2 wire communication and how it will fetch information from signals?

Comment: The questions are way too vague to make sense. Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you talking about HART protocol where digital information is transmitted over a 4-20mA current loop?

Comment: If you are in some doubt, I will say an analog carries the digital using the technique called modulation.

Answer (score 5):

In copper wire DSL the solution used is to split the frequency space into two domains: The frequency range below e.g. 3.4 kHz is used to transmit analogue sound (i.e. telephone conversation) and the frequency range above for the digital communication protocols. At the endpoint a frequency splitter is used which allows recovering the two different signals at two outputs.

Comment: And, actually, the digital part is really another analog signal.  Think of a modem, with tones, only it's operating at a frequency so high you can't hear it.